# "Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled" since support lib 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

All recyclerviews crashes sometimes, when I scroll the list fast, since I've updated to support lib 25.0.0. There is no layout animator and the everything worked fine, with support lib < 25.

The exception is thrown in the RecyclerView, because holder.itemView.getparent() is not null

```
    if (holder.isScrap() || holder.itemView.getParent() != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:"
                            + holder.isScrap() + " isAttached:"
                            + (holder.itemView.getParent() != null));
        }
```

Does anyone else experienced that behavior?

Comment: You may have better luck if you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, along with the full stack trace of the crash.

Comment: same issue here and it also only happened after I upgraded support library to version 25.0.0. Some body create an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226353&can=1&q=reportedby%3DDeveloper%20-has%3Atriaged%20-has%3Apriority%20component%3DSupport-Libraries%20-has%3Ablocked&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=1400 but it looks like the google support library team close it since lack of reproduce step.

Comment: BTW I only face this issue under GridLayoutManager. Where I use LinearLayoutManager, it looks all fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To prevent the crash from this issue, you need to call `setHasStableIds(boolean)` from your adapter and pass the parameter as true:

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

Explanation:
The problem occurs when you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

The `recyclerView` then calls `detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);` It temporarily detaches and scraps all currently attached child views. Views will be scrapped into the given `Recycler`. The `Recycler` may prefer to reuse scrap views.

Then `scrapOrRecycleView(recycler, (int) position, (View) child);` is called. This function checks if "hasStableIds" is true or false. If its false then you get the following error :

> "Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled."

Stable IDs allow the `View` (`RecyclerView`, `ListView`, etc.) to optimize for the case when items remain the same between `notifyDataSetChanged` calls.
`hasStableIds() == true` indicates whether the item ids are stable across changes to the underlying data.

If the item ids are stable then it can be reused by the view i.e. "recycled" making the process of re-rendering after the call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` efficient. If item ids are not stable, there is no guarantee that the item has been recycled as there is no way to track them.

Note: Setting `setHasStableIds()` to true is not a way to request stable IDs, but to tell Recycler/List/Grid Views that you are providing the said stability.

Comment: would u please assist me with quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408085/gapworker-with-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycled-isscrapfalse-isa

Answer (score -1):

It can also happen if you set `android:orientation="horizontal"` on `RecyclerView` in XML. Removing it will prevent the crash.

Comment: Anyone who wants to downvote this, please add that line to your `RecyclerView` and check if you get this crash.